# Scheme: pattern matching syntax

Tags: syntax, scheme, pattern-matching, racket

I need to be able to match patterns like this:

'(PARAMS (x) (lambda (y) (+ x y)))

but the best I can think of returns this:

```
(match `(PARAMS (x) (lambda (y) (+ x y)))
  [`(PARAMS (,var) (lambda (,arg) (,stmt))) 'yep]
  [otherise 'nope])
```

==>

```
nope
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't put `,stmt` inside parens.

(And BTW, all of these questions are Racket specific, so please use the `racket` tag.)

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't realize it was Racket.  I am working from a book on Scheme and using Drracket.

Comment: The `match` that you're using in DrRacket is not something that is standard in all scheme implementations.